# How to send data with fetch in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch-api

I'm doing a multiple checkbox filter, and I have to send to the server an object with a post method. How can I use fetch to do that? Can I send data using fetch? And from the server I have to receive a filtered list. 
Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to use fetch. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question as-is is too broad and the likely response you’re gonna get is being asked, What you have tried already? You might want to start by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can specify the fetch method with 'POST'

example code here from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
    return fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstParam: 'yourValue',
        secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.success;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```